# How to make funtion call in Django views.py to render same template but with different queries?

Tags: python, django

class CartView(View):

```
def get(self,request,pk): 
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if Smart_phone.objects.filter(name=pk):
            product = Smart_phone.objects.filter(name=pk)
            items = product
            for item in items:
                if item.instock>0 :   
                    context ={'product':product}
                    return render(request,'customer_purchase/cart.html',context)
                else:
                    return render(request,'customer_purchase/home')
                
        elif Tabs.objects.filter(name=pk):
            product = Tabs.objects.filter(name=pk)
            items = product
            for item in items:
                if item.instock>0 :   
                            context ={'product':product}
                            return render(request,'customer_purchase/cart.html',context)
                else:
                    return render(request,'customer_purchase/home.html')
                        
        elif Smart_watch.objects.filter(name=pk):
            product = Smart_watch.objects.filter(name=pk)
            items = product
            for item in items:
                if item.instock>0 :   
                    context ={'product':product}
                    return render(request,'customer_purchase/cart.html',context)
                else:
                    return render(request,'customer_purchase/home')

    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

Here the loop is common for every query . Hence i want to call a function ,that does the rendering process . 'instock' is  a field common to the models thats i am using here